# How does one force a stack to be removed in AWS Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have stack called BasicWebServerStack in AWS from the tutorial. It is currently in a bad state of  ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and can not be updated. Not that big a deal. Now I would like to be able to remove this stack by running this command

Powershell ...

```
 Remove-CFNStack -StackName 'BasicWebServerStack' -Force Yes
```

The problem is, I can not seem to get the proper syntax for the force switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -Force parameter is a switch, not a boolean, and just suppresses confirmation that you really want to perform the delete (it's not passed to the service). So the syntax you want is:

```
Remove-CFNStack -StackName 'BasicWebServerStack' -Force
```